# Using C for performance intensive operation (android)

Tags: java, android, c, sdk

I want to make an Android App where I want to use the normal java sdk for the main ui operations.

The app will make some picture analysis which will be performance intensive and so I want to make this part in pure C.

Do I have to make 2 Projects for that? (One with the java sdk, and one with the ndk) Or is it possible to mix them in one project?

How should I structure a project , where I want to evacuate the performance intensive Code part?! I heard about using jni for that?!

Thanks!

Matthias

Comment: Keep it simple and implement it in Java first to see whether you really have a performance problem. If not, I think it won't be worth the effort (we do intensive number crunching and switched from C++ to Java 3 years ago - guess what: the calculations now are faster than before... your mileage may vary, and I have no idea if android will be a different thing).

Comment: One project is enough in Eclipse. See [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). There are not so many different ways to structure your project, the C codes will be in their own folder and Java codes in their own.

Comment: If you are trying it with Java only keep in mind, that the Dalvik-VM that's used on android is slow with allocating memory... An example of combined Java and C-Code can be found in the [Squawk-VM](http://java.net/projects/squawk/pages/SquawkDevelopment).

Comment: as long as you're not a coding prodigy , its really rare and a so hard-if possible- job to get a significant improvement of performance with C usage , if your java code is structured properly for the cause